# Send a Slack message to a user on a channel using Python

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

I am using Slack real time messaging API with Python and want to send a message to a user on a channel, using@ like @hellobot create a directory test2002.

The given code doesn't work:

```
slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel='#bot',text="create directory test2002",username='ecstesting1989')
```

If I use:

```
slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel='#bot',text="@hellobot create directory test2002",username='ecstesting1989')
```

This sends the command as @hellobot create directory test2002 in text format and doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

use  **< !channel >**

Also , check [this](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users)

I have done this [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22Hello%20%3C!channel%7C%3E%22%7D)
put json as

```
 {
   "text": "Hello <!channel|>"
 }
```

you will get

```
 Hello @channel
```